# Reference request: Analytic study of the trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, reference-request

I'm looking for a source (or sources) which develop a *complete* theory of the trigonometric functions with no reference to circle geometry. That is, it is purely analytic. The starting point could be (for example)

$$\arcsin x := \int_0^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} $$

or alternatively defining $\sin$ and $\cos$ as solutions to differential equations.

Comment: I think Rudin PMA has such a treatment.

Comment: Maxwell Rosenlicht's intro to Analysis book goes the differential equation route.

Answer (score 1):

Richard R. Goldberg, Methods of Real Analysis, 2nd Ed., Wiley and Sons,  1976

Answer (score 0):

The Real Numbers and Real Analysis
by Ethan D. Bloch

Comment: How strange, I don't remember typing that at all. Must have been a mistake, sorry for that.

Comment: By the way, the answer is yes, I am familiar with the book. I still have a copy of it that I bought when I was in grade 12. It's a good book for anyone who love rigor to the extreme (including myself when I was younger :) ) but it's a bit too wordy in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Ahlfors, if you are willing to fill in the details.